# How do I write the left and right arrow as a character in Racket?

Tags: racket

I'm trying to make a graphical editor in Racket using List of characters, but I can't figure out how to write a left and right arrow as a character.

I've tried #\right and #\rightarrow but neither works.

I expected it to work because #\backspace does work, especially because  "\b" works as a string and "left" and "right" also work as strings for left arrow and right arrow.

Answer (score 0):

The list of characters with names are here:

https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/reader.html?q=characters#%28part._parse-character%29

I am not sure what you mean by "left space" and "right space" though.

Comment: If you want to display arrows, you can use `#\←` and `#\→`. If you want to move a cursor, you need to provide more context.

Comment: Just to explain the above and what else you can do I'm pretty sure - `#\←` is just the same as #\u2190. You should be able to use unicode and there are a ton of different symbols you could use. Not totally sure what Rackets supports but doesn't seem limited to named characters...

Left arrow unicode: https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2190